# Create sheets based on range (ignoring empty cells)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create new sheets named after a range of values after I push a button, but I get the following error: "Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet failed" when I set MyRange

My current sheet is "V-Class GC" and the starting cell is U2
Here's what I've got so far:

```
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range(Sheets("V-Class GC").[u2], Sheets("V-Class GC").Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Len(MyCell.Text) > 0 Then
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
    End If
Next MyCell
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is in cell U2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to a range with method .Range of the Sheets class.

```
Set MyRange = Range(Sheets("V-Class GC").Range("U2"), Sheets("V-Class GC").Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp))
```

When you are trying to understand what's happening when you refer to a range, try to select it and work with a single cell at time, in your case you could try to select the single cell range, using Range.[u2] you would quickly found the error because of the error raised by excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim Foo As Variant, FooRange As Range

Sheets("V-Class GC").Select
Set FooRange = Range("u2", Range("u2").End(xLDown))

For Each Foo In FooRange
    If Len(Foo.Value) > 0 Then
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Foo.Value
    End If
Next
```

Your problem is likely coming from how you define your range to iterate.